# attach two hdds to a computer having 500W smps

Tags: hard-drive, power-management

I have a desktop system installed with a 250 GB hdd (seagate sata II) this system is having a power supply of 500W (not sure if it is 650W but not more than that) the power supply is a local brand.

Will it be safe to attach a second 250 GB sata II hdd on the same system.

Safe in the sense that the system may not fall short of power at any time.

**My system's config is as follows**

Core2Duo processor

Mercury cabinet having an additional fan (small one)

sata dvd writer 52X

windows xp sp 2

ASUS motherboard (intel G965 express chipset)

If the above specified power supply is not sufficient for above configuration of system then please suggest the appropriate power supply (including watts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At spinup, for 5-10 seconds, the 7200rpm type will use ~35W max (12V type). During normal use they'll use 10W-13W. Sources: [A](http://www.seagate.com/staticfiles/support/disc/manuals/desktop/Barracuda%207200.10/100402371k.pdf), [B](http://www.seagate.com/staticfiles/support/disc/manuals/desktop/Barracuda%207200.8/100325576f.pdf). Go for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can attach upto 4 HDD of 250 GB for your above mentioned configurations. Don't worry at all and go for it.